# Does importing other contracts affects my contract's size?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, bytecode, optimization

If I have

```
Contract B{
  ...
}

Contract A{
   B b;
   ...
}
```

Does A's contract size equals to B's contract size plus A's other implementation? or does it only increased by the size that b object takes?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

Take a look at the following and simple contracts:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {

  B b;

  constructor(B _b) {
    b = _b;
  }

  function getValue() public view returns(uint256) {
    return b.getN() * 5;
  }

}

contract B {

  uint256 public n = 5;

  function getN() public view returns(uint256) {
    return n;
  }

}
```

I have a `B` contract that has a public `n` state variable and a `getN()` function.

When I compiled contract A, the byte code has is `1184` characters, take a look:

```
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
```

When I add more properties and functions to the `B` contract but I don't use them in the `A` contract, the `A` bytecode after compile stays exactly the same, check:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {

  B b;

  constructor(B _b) {
    b = _b;
  }

  function getValue() public view returns(uint256) {
    return b.getN() * 5;
  }

}

contract B {

  uint256 public n = 5;
  address public owner = msg.sender;

  function getN() public view returns(uint256) {
    return n;
  }

  function decreaseN() public {
    n--;
  }

  function increaseN() public {
    n++;
  }
  
}
```

The `B` contract has 1 more property and 2 more functions, so it itself should have a bigger size after compiling, but `A` contract does not get affected by that because I didn't use any of those functions in the `A` contract, so `A` contract stays the same, with `1184` caracters:

```
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
```

Comment: So how it works? It’s only getting bigger by the functions I use?

Comment: Yes, but that's because you are adding extra logic to your contract, not because it is importing anything from the other contract, it just keeps the method signature of the `B` contract and uses the `B`'s contract address to call it with something like: `contractBAddress.call(functionSignature)`.

Comment: But let’s say I only deployed contract A, how it knows to create for example new contract B and manipulate it?

Comment: It doesn't. That Solidity code it's just sugar code. It really just uses the address of the deployed contract to interact with it. It saves in the bytecode the function signatures of the `B` contract that contract `A` calls, so it knows how to call and interact with those functions.

Try to decompile the bytecode I provided here and you will see what I mean: https://ethervm.io/decompile

Comment: I understand, but what happens if the contract doesn’t has any address. As I said, if I only deployed contract A and not contract B. how it manages this situation?

Comment: In that case, the `B` reference will actually point to the 0 address and errors may occur while trying to call it.